# CakePHP : having different layout files for backend and frontend

Tags: cakephp, layout, routes, frontend, backend

Is it possible to have 2 different layout files in the app > view > Layouts folder. The reason that I'm asking this is that I already have my backoffice, but don't know how to proceed in making the structure for the frontoffice.

The routes of the views in my backoffice use the prefix admin and use the default.ctp as layout. I actually want that file to be admin_default.ctp so I can use the default.ctp for my frontoffice views.

My question now is how can I separate those layout files. What I want to achieve is that some controllers/views use default.ctp (front) and other controllers/views use the admin_default.ctp (back). Is this a good approach or is it better to consider an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply you can use `$this->layout` to specify your custom layout in controller.

this [**article**](http://alvinalexander.com/php/cakephp-multiple-layouts-solution-controllers) may be useful for your question

Comment: So for each action inside that controller I need to do this : $this->layout = 'admin_layout'; ?

Comment: only when you want to define custom layout for a page , so you need to set custom layout in the controller. other pages uses own default layout.

Comment: Ok but it always have to be inside an action? So you can't say to an entire controller to take the custom layout?

Comment: you can set layout on before render in appController to use every where

Comment: For some reason it won't override the default layout when I use $this->layout = 'newlayout'; inside an action. I'm searching for it atm.

Comment: Found it :) I was typing $this->layout = 'newlayout'; in the wrong action.

Answer (score 1):

In your AppController's beforeFilter, just check if it's admin prefix, and set the layout accordingly:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

public function beforeFilter() {
    if($this->params['prefix'] == 'admin' && $this->name !== 'CakeError') {
        $this->layout = "admin"; // set the layout
    }
}

//...
```

Another nice thing you can do after determining it's the admin is is force SSL (often a good idea for back-ends):

```
$this->Security->requireSecure();  // inside the above if block
```